# differentiability: a question involving interchange of limits

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous and $C^1(\,]a,b])$.
Suppose
$$ f'(x)\xrightarrow[x\to a+]{}{}l $$
1) If $l\in\mathbb{R}$ I manage to prove that $\exists\,f'(a)=l$ (I used uniform continuity of $f'$), hence $f\in C^1([a,b])$.

2) Now if $l=\infty$ I would say that $f'(a)=\infty$, i.e. $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\xrightarrow[h\to0+]{}\infty$ . Is it true? or further hypothesis (e.g. concavity of $f$) are needed? How can I prove it?

Comment: $\exists f'(a)=l$ is nonsense. Do you mean you've proved that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ with derivative $l$?

Comment: I mean there exists $f'(a)$ and it is equal to $l$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mean value theorem, you don't even need continuity of the derivative, just existance of a (one-sided) limit. for simplicity assume $(a,b) = (0,1)$ then 
$$ \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = f^{'}(\epsilon_h)$$
where $\epsilon_h \in (0,h)$
take $lim_{h \rightarrow 0}$. RHS has a limit by assumption, because when $h \rightarrow 0$ then also $\epsilon_h \rightarrow 0$ hence the LHS also has a limit and they're equal

Comment: It is simpler that I thought. Thank youvery much!